# .net dynamically generated radio button attached to datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I've got an asp.net datalist which basically functions as a repeater, creating a list of images in a grid, 4 images per row. I have a radio button being generated for each cell, with a hidden field that contains the ID of the image in each cell.

```
 <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlCertImages" RepeatColumns="4">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="10px">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rb" runat="server" />            
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_rb" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CertificateImageID")%>' /> 
         </td>
         <td>
         <a href="ResizeImage.aspx?filename=ImagesCerts/<%# Eval("ImageSrc")%>&width=400&height=375" class="preview"><img src="ReSizeImage.aspx?filename=ImagesCerts/<%# Eval("ImageSrc")%>&width=150&height=137" /></a>
         </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

The ultimate goal is to allow them to choose only ONE image. First, is this the best method for this? Second, once the form is submitted, how can I loop through the datalist to see which item was chosen?

Comment: When you have multiple radio buttons directly bound within a control, only one of those radio buttons can be checked at once. So, yes; if you want to select only one image, radio buttons are just the thing you need.

Comment: Good, at least I'm in the right direction. Any help on the second part of the question - how can I grab the chosen radio button?